# How to resolve runtime error ('800a01a8' ) in VBScript (classic ASP)?

Tags: graph, asp-classic, vbscript

I have following classic asp code:

```
     <BODY>

  <%   
 'In this example, we show how to connect FusionCharts to a database.
 'For the sake of ease, we've used an Access database which is present in
 '../DB/FactoryDB.mdb. It just contains two tables, which are linked to each
 'other. 

 'Database Objects - Initialization
 Dim oRs, oRs2, strQuery
 'strXML will be used to store the entire XML document generated
 Dim strXML

 'Create the recordset to retrieve data
  Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 'Generate the chart element
  strXML = "<graph caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity'         decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' numberSuffix=' Units' pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>"

 'Iterate through each factory
strQuery = "select * from deal_price"
Set oRs = oConnection.Execute(strQuery)

While Not oRs.Eof
'Now create second recordset to get details for this factory
Set oRs2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strQuery = "select sum(price) as TotOutput from deal_price where deal_id=" &  ors("deal_id")
Set oRs2 = oConnection.Execute(strQuery) 
'Generate <set name='..' value='..'/> 
strXML = strXML & "<set name='" & ors("name") & "' value='" & ors2("TotOutput") & "' />"
'Close recordset
Set oRs2 = Nothing
oRs.MoveNext
Wend
'Finally, close <chart> element
strXML = strXML & "</chart>"
Set oRs = nothing

'Create the chart - Pie 3D Chart with data from strXML
 Call renderChart("MyWeb/includes/FCF_Pie2D.swf", "", strXML, "FactorySum", 650, 450)
 %>
 </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

DBconnection file code:

```
Dim oConnection
Set oConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=MA-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial      Catalog=test; User ID=missy; Password=hello;"
```

I am getting a run time error on the line which says the following:
**Set oRs = oConnection.Execute(strQuery)**.

I can not seem to work out, where I am going wrong. Any Assistant would be very much appreciated. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Is oConnection defined in your DBConn.asp?

Comment: Dear @ andrew, I checked the variables but I still getting the same error..:(

Comment: you are opening and then closing the connection and then setting it to Nothing.  copy oConnection.Close and Set oConnection = Nothing and put it after Set oRs = oConnection.Execute(strQuery) in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because your include file (DBConn.asp) is opening the connection, closing it and setting it to Nothing.

Remove from the DBConn.asp file:

```
oConnection.Close
Set oConnection = Nothing
```

Change your code:

```
   'Create the recordset to retrieve data
        Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

       'Generate the chart element
        strXML = "<graph caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity'         decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' numberSuffix=' Units' pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>"

     'Iterate through each factory
      strQuery = "select * from deal_price"
      Set oRs = oConnection.Execute(strQuery)

      While Not oRs.Eof
      'Now create second recordset to get details for this factory
      Set oRs2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
      strQuery = "select sum(Quantity) as TotOutput from Factory_Output where FactoryId=" &  ors("FactoryId")
      Set oRs2 = oConnection.Execute(strQuery) 
      'Generate <set name='..' value='..'/> 
      strXML = strXML & "<set name='" & ors("FactoryName") & "' value='" & ors2("TotOutput") & "' />"
      'Close recordset
      Set oRs2 = Nothing
      oRs.MoveNext
    Wend
     'Finally, close <chart> element
      strXML = strXML & "</chart>"
      Set oRs = nothing

    'Create the chart - Pie 3D Chart with data from strXML
     Call renderChart("../../FusionCharts/FCF_Pie3D.swf", "", strXML, "FactorySum", 650, 450)
'Create the recordset to retrieve data
    Set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

   'Generate the chart element
    strXML = "<graph caption='Factory Output report' subCaption='By Quantity'         decimalPrecision='0' showNames='1' numberSuffix=' Units' pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>"

 'Iterate through each factory
  strQuery = "select * from deal_price"
  Set oRs = oConnection.Execute(strQuery)

  While Not oRs.Eof
  'Now create second recordset to get details for this factory
  Set oRs2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  strQuery = "select sum(Quantity) as TotOutput from Factory_Output where FactoryId=" &  ors("FactoryId")
  Set oRs2 = oConnection.Execute(strQuery) 
  'Generate <set name='..' value='..'/> 
  strXML = strXML & "<set name='" & ors("FactoryName") & "' value='" & ors2("TotOutput") & "' />"
  'Close recordset
  Set oRs2 = Nothing
  oRs.MoveNext
Wend
 'Finally, close <chart> element
  strXML = strXML & "</chart>"
  Set oRs = nothing

'Create the chart - Pie 3D Chart with data from strXML
 Call renderChart("../../FusionCharts/FCF_Pie3D.swf", "", strXML, "FactorySum", 650, 450)


'Add these lines back in as you are done processing your records
 oConnection.Close
 Set oConnection = Nothing

 %>
```

Comment: thank so much for your help. I am currently new to classic asp, so I'm so slow to pick up these silly mistakes. Thank you for your time and help.